# GeoServer: Cross layer filtering with current bbox

Tags: geoserver, wms, cql-filter, crossfilter

I have two layers "building" and "soil" on a French region and I have about 1 million land and 500,000 buildings. I am trying to filter on the WMS query to get the land with the individual type buildings. I added in my CQL_filter

> INTERSECTS(wkb_geometry, collectGeometries(queryCollection('poc:building', 'wkb_geometry', 'type=''individual''')))

Unfortunately the number of data is too large and therefore it exceeds my memory limit.
Is there a way to add the current BBOX so that it only filters on displayed entities?